# Building VIM with python support in Cygwin?

Tags: vim, python, cygwin, perl

I'm trying to build VIM with Python/Perl support under Cygwin.

Has anyone done this and can shed some light how this is achieved?

Comment: why do you need the cygwin-version of vim? the native win32-version is built with python support ...

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall your cygwin vim
2. Get the source vim with Mercurial (or just download it, but using mercurial is recommended, see http://www.vim.org/download.php), in your cygwin terminal type:

   ```
   hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
   ```
3. Build VIM

   ```
   cd vim
   ./configure --enable-rubyinterp --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-gui=no --enable-multibyte
   make && make install
   ```
4. Check if everything worked

   ```
   vim --version
   ........ +perl ..... +python ...... +ruby
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what you mean. If i remember correctly vim is already provided as a binary for cygwin. http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#gvim

If you would just like to have python support in vim you might want to have a vim plugin installed.

Check out http://www.vim.org/scripts for plugins.

Here is for example python code completion i use: 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850